# Order List marker

Tags: html, css

Hi is it possible to start my marker on second element of my list.

Current

```
<ol>
<li>some image <a>some link</a></li>
<li>some image <a>some link</a></li>
<li>some image <a>some link</a></li>
</ol>
```

Wanted

```
<ol>
<li>some image  1.<a>some link</a></li>
<li>some image 2.<a>some link</a></li>
<li>some image 3.<a>some link</a></li>
</ol>
```

Do advise me thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create you own marker:

```css
ol {
  list-style:none;
  counter-reset:num;
}
ol li a::before {
  content:counter(num) ". ";
  counter-increment:num;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>some image <a>some link</a></li>
  <li>some image <a>some link</a></li>
  <li>some image <a>some link</a></li>
</ol>
```